# Create and fill a 2D Array in Scala

Tags: java, arrays, scala, multidimensional-array, intellij-idea

I have just started looking into Scala, and I decided to make a roguelike to get my feet wet. I come from a Java background, and I am having trouble working with the Scala Arrays.

When I try to make a level, what I call a room, I picture a two dimensional array with `#` as walls. I try to use, as I understand it, a Scala nested for-loop to place the `#` wall characters when i || j are 0, or when i || j is at the end of the array. Inside the braces of the for-loop, I have `temp(i, j) = '#'` which is giving me the error `"Expression of type Char doesn't conform to expected type, Nothing"` in my IDE, IntelliJ.

I have posted my code below, and if you could help me format and/or work with my Array correctly, that would be great.

```
class Room
{
    val room = generate

    def generate: Array[Char] =
    {
        var temp = Array[Char](10, 10)

        for (i: Int <- 0 to temp.length; j: Int <- 0 to temp.length)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == temp.length-1 || j == temp.length-1)
                temp(i, j) = '#'
        }

        return temp
    }

    def print: Unit =
    {
        for (i <- 0 to 10)
        {
            var line: String = ""
            for (j <- 0 to 10)
            {
                line += room(i, j)
            }
            println(line)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`var temp = Array[Char](10, 10)` creates a 1-dimension `Array` containing two linefeed characters (10 being its value in ascii).

You'll want to use `var temp = Array.ofDim[Char](10,10)` instead. You can then access a cell using `temp(i)(j)` (and not `temp(i, j)`).

Also note that `for (i <- 0 to 10) {}` will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You'll want to use `for (i <- 0 until 10) {}` instead.

---

You could also use the `Array.tabulate` method :

```
// Dummy implementation
scala> def calculateCellValue(i: Int, j: Int) = 
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == 9 || j == 9)  '#' else 'x'

scala> val temp = Array.tabulate(10,10)(calculateCellValue)
temp: Array[Array[Char]] = Array(Array(#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #),
                                 Array(#, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, #),
                                 Array(#, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, #),
                                 Array(#, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, #),
                                 Array(#, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, #), 
                                 Array(#, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, #), 
                                 Array(#, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, #), 
                                 Array(#, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, #), 
                                 Array(#, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, #), 
                                 Array(#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #))
```

Comment: The REPL printer doesn't actually align arrays like that, but maybe it should. Since you enumerate the Javaisms, add that var and return are not needed. I thought I was the only bored person online.

Answer (score 0):

You want `Array.ofDim` instead of `Array[Char](10, 10)`, which is an array of two elements.

Also, your braces are on the wrong line.

```
package dims

class Room {
    val room = generate

    def generate = {
        val temp = Array.ofDim[Char](10, 10)

        for (i <- 0 until temp.length; j <- 0 until temp(0).length) {
            temp(i)(j) =
              if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == temp.length-1 || j == temp(0).length-1) '#' else ' '
        }
        temp
    }

    def print(): Unit = {
        for (i <- 0 until room.length) {
            var line: String = ""
            for (j <- 0 until room(0).length) {
                line += room(i)(j)
            }
            println(line)
        }
    }
}
object Test extends App {
  val r = new Room
  r.print()
}
```